# How to get the blender bundled installation of python out of path

Tags: python, windows, blender

So I have blender installed and then also installed the latest version python (3.11) in order to write some scripts (unrelated to blender). For one of the scripts I wanted to use pystray. So I opened command promp and entered `python -m pip install pystray`. It installs just fine and i go back to run my code and it doesn't recognize pystray. That's weird I thought so I go to the scripts folder for the python install and nothing is there but pip. Go back to command line and try to reinstall and it says it's already installed but gives a path that is in the blender directory.

So really I just want to get that path out of PATH so that when I'm in command promp and I type `python` it's only pointing at my version of python and not the blender one.

I went to system properties > environment variables > path but it wasn't there so I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found my own answer as I was typing the question. Posting here for other dumbo's like myself.

Blender is adding to the system variables PATH not the user variables PATH.